# XSLT move namespace declarations from child to parent element

Tags: xslt

I have this source:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soapenv:Body>
    <sc:GetFdrRewardsResponse xmlns:sc="http://somecompany.com/soa/cardaccount1.1/schema"
    xmlns:sc_1="http://somecompany.com/soa/common1.1/schema"
    xmlns:sc_2="http://somecompany.com/soa/common/schema"
    xmlns:sc_3="http://somecompany.com/soa/cardaccount/schema">
      <sc_1:ResponseCode>0000</sc_1:ResponseCode>
      <sc_1:ResponseMessage>Successful Execution</sc_1:ResponseMessage>
      <sc_1:CorrelationId>1234</sc_1:CorrelationId>
      <sc:FdrRewards>
        <sc_2:BankNumber>0175</sc_2:BankNumber>
        <sc:IsRewardsMember>true</sc:IsRewardsMember>
        <sc:IsEligibleToRedeem>true</sc:IsEligibleToRedeem>
        <sc_3:AmazingRewardsBalance>10442.00</sc_3:AmazingRewardsBalance>
        <sc_3:CashBackSavingsBalance>0.00</sc_3:CashBackSavingsBalance>
      </sc:FdrRewards>
    </sc:GetFdrRewardsResponse>
  </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

And need this result:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soapenv:Body>
    <sc_3:GetFdrRewardsResponse 
       xmlns:sc_1="http://somecompany.com/soa/common1.1/schema"
       xmlns:sc_2="http://somecompany.com/soa/common/schema"
       xmlns:sc_3="http://somecompany.com/soa/cardaccount/schema" >
      <sc_1:ResponseCode>0000</sc_1:ResponseCode>
      <sc_1:ResponseMessage >Successful Execution</sc_1:ResponseMessage>
      <sc_1:CorrelationId >1234</sc_1:CorrelationId>
      <sc_3:FdrRewards>
        <sc_2:BankNumber >0175</sc_2:BankNumber>
        <sc_3:AmazingRewardsBalance>10442.00</sc_3:AmazingRewardsBalance>
        <sc_3:CashBackSavingsBalance>0.00</sc_3:CashBackSavingsBalance>
      </sc_3:FdrRewards>
    </sc_3:GetFdrRewardsResponse>
  </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

I am using this transform:

```
<xsl:stylesheet
  version="1.0"
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xmlns:sc="http://somecompany.com/soa/cardaccount1.1/schema"
  xmlns:sc_1="http://somecompany.com/soa/common1.1/schema"
    xmlns:sc_2="http://somecompany.com/soa/common/schema"
    xmlns:sc_3="http://somecompany.com/soa/cardaccount/schema"
  >

  <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:template match="node() | @*">
    <xsl:copy>
       <xsl:apply-templates select="node() | @*" />
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="sc:IsRewardsMember"/>
  <xsl:template match="sc:IsEligibleToRedeem"/>

  <xsl:template match="sc:*">
    <xsl:element name="sc_3:{local-name()}">
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:element>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Which almost works. It puts the resulting namespace declarations on each child element, rather than declaring it once in the parent element.

Any ideas? A complete XSLT file would be fantastic.....

Comment: Note, you are not just "moving the namespace declarations", you are changing the names of the elements (the name consists of a local name plus namespace URI). If you want to generate namespace declarations on an element where they aren't actually needed, then in XSLT 2.0 use the xsl:namespace instruction; in 1.0 use xsl:copy to copy the namespace node from somewhere in the input to where it is needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I change your XSLT to the following:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:sc="http://somecompany.com/soa/cardaccount1.1/schema" xmlns:sc_1="http://somecompany.com/soa/common1.1/schema" xmlns:sc_2="http://somecompany.com/soa/common/schema" xmlns:sc_3="http://somecompany.com/soa/cardaccount/schema">
    <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes" indent="yes"/> 
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="node() | @*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node() | @*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="sc:IsRewardsMember"/>
    <xsl:template match="sc:IsEligibleToRedeem"/>

    <xsl:template match="sc:GetFdrRewardsResponse">
        <sc_3:GetFdrRewardsResponse>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
        </sc_3:GetFdrRewardsResponse>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The desired output is almost what you want, but still the following namespaces are in the output:

```
xmlns:sc="http://somecompany.com/soa/cardaccount1.1/schema"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
```

But it should not hurt anybody

Comment: Just add an `exclude-output-prefixes="sc xsi"` to get rid of them.

Comment: This works great! Thanks. I can't mod up because I don't have enough points.

Comment: Adding the exclude-output-prefixes attribute causes child elements to have sc namespace declarations:

<sc_1:ResponseCode xmlns:sc="http://somecompany.com/soa/cardaccount1.1/schema">