# Declare added namespace in xml header

Tags: xml, xslt, namespaces

I want to move and declare namespace `xmlns:ns2="urn:us:gov:hhs:acf:cseiwo` in header node `EIWORoot` and remove the declaration from child nodes.

My input XML:

```xml
<ns1:EIWORoot xmlns:ns1="urn:us:gov:hhs:acf:eiwo">
   <ns1:DocumentFileHeader>
      <ns2:ControlNumber xmlns:ns2="urn:us:gov:hhs:acf:cseiwo"></ns2:ControlNumber>
      <ns2:StateTribeTerritoryCode xmlns:ns2="urn:us:gov:hhs:acf:cseiwo"></ns2:StateTribeTerritoryCode>
      <ns2:EINText xmlns:ns2="urn:us:gov:hhs:acf:cseiwo"></ns2:EINText>
      <ns2:CreationDate xmlns:ns2="urn:us:gov:hhs:acf:cseiwo"></ns2:CreationDate>
      <ns2:CreationTime xmlns:ns2="urn:us:gov:hhs:acf:cseiwo"></ns2:CreationTime>
      <ns1:DocumentCode>FHA</ns1:DocumentCode>
   </ns1:DocumentFileHeader>
   <ns1:EIWOBatch>
      <ns1:DocumentBatchHeader>
         <ns2:ControlNumber xmlns:ns2="urn:us:gov:hhs:acf:cseiwo"></ns2:ControlNumber>
         <ns2:StateTribeTerritoryCode xmlns:ns2="urn:us:gov:hhs:acf:cseiwo"></ns2:StateTribeTerritoryCode>
         <ns2:EINText xmlns:ns2="urn:us:gov:hhs:acf:cseiwo"></ns2:EINText>
         <ns2:CreationDate xmlns:ns2="urn:us:gov:hhs:acf:cseiwo"></ns2:CreationDate>
         <ns2:CreationTime xmlns:ns2="urn:us:gov:hhs:acf:cseiwo"></ns2:CreationTime>
         <ns1:DocumentCode></ns1:DocumentCode>
      </ns1:DocumentBatchHeader>
      <ns1:EIWO>
         <ns1:IdentifyingInfo>
            <ns1:DocumentDate></ns1:DocumentDate>
            <ns1:DocumentActionCode></ns1:DocumentActionCode>
            <ns1:CaseIdentifier></ns1:CaseIdentifier>
            <ns1:OrderIdentifier></ns1:OrderIdentifier>
            <ns1:DocumentTrackingNumber></ns1:DocumentTrackingNumber>
         </ns1:IdentifyingInfo>
         <ns1:Authority>
            <ns1:IssuingStateTribeTerritoryName></ns1:IssuingStateTribeTerritoryName>
            <ns1:IssuingTribunalName></ns1:IssuingTribunalName>
            <ns1:EmploymentPlaceName></ns1:EmploymentPlaceName>
            <ns1:GovernmentOfficialName></ns1:GovernmentOfficialName>
            <ns1:IssuingOfficialTitleText></ns1:IssuingOfficialTitleText>
            <ns1:SendEmployeeCopyIndicator></ns1:SendEmployeeCopyIndicator>
         </ns1:Authority>
         <ns1:LegalProvision>
            <ns1:PenaltyLiabilityText></ns1:PenaltyLiabilityText>
            <ns1:AntiDiscriminationText></ns1:AntiDiscriminationText>
            <ns1:PayeeWithholdingLimitsText></ns1:PayeeWithholdingLimitsText>
         </ns1:LegalProvision>
         <ns1:Person>
            <ns1:Employee>
               <ns1:PersonName></ns1:PersonName>
               <ns1:PersonSSN></ns1:PersonSSN>
               <ns1:PersonBirthDate></ns1:PersonBirthDate>
            </ns1:Employee>
            <ns1:Child>
               <ns1:PersonName>
                  <ns1:LastName></ns1:LastName>
                  <ns1:FirstName></ns1:FirstName>
               </ns1:PersonName>
               <ns1:PersonBirthDate></ns1:PersonBirthDate>
            </ns1:Child>
         </ns1:Person>
      </ns1:EIWO>
   </ns1:EIWOBatch>
   <ns1:DocumentFileTrailer>
      <ns2:ControlNumber xmlns:ns2="urn:us:gov:hhs:acf:cseiwo"></ns2:ControlNumber>
      <ns2:SentCounts xmlns:ns2="urn:us:gov:hhs:acf:cseiwo"></ns2:SentCounts>
      <ns1:DocumentCode></ns1:DocumentCode>
   </ns1:DocumentFileTrailer>
</ns1:EIWORoot>
```

My XSL code:

```xml
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:ns1="urn:us:gov:hhs:acf:eiwo" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
   <xsl:template match="/">
      <eiwo:EIWORoot>
         <eiwo:DocumentFileHeader>
            <cseiwo:ControlNumber>
               <xsl:value-of select="/ns1:EIWORoot/ns1:DocumentFileHeader/ns2:ControlNumber"/>
            </cseiwo:ControlNumber>
            <cseiwo:EINText>
               <xsl:value-of select="/ns1:EIWORoot/ns1:DocumentFileHeader/ns2:EINText"/>
            </cseiwo:EINText>
            <cseiwo:CreationDate>
               <xsl:value-of select="/ns1:EIWORoot/ns1:DocumentFileHeader/ns2:CreationDate"/>
            </cseiwo:CreationDate>
            <cseiwo:CreationTime>
               <xsl:value-of select="/ns1:EIWORoot/ns1:DocumentFileHeader/ns2:CreationTime"/>
            </cseiwo:CreationTime>
            <xsl:for-each select="/ns1:EIWORoot/ns1:DocumentFileHeader/ns1:DocumentCode">
               <eiwo:DocumentCode>
                  <xsl:value-of select="."/>
               </eiwo:DocumentCode>
            </xsl:for-each>
         </eiwo:DocumentFileHeader>
         <eiwo:EIWOBatch>
            <eiwo:DocumentBatchHeader>
               <cseiwo:ControlNumber>
                  <xsl:value-of select="/ns1:EIWORoot/ns1:EIWOBatch/ns1:DocumentBatchHeader/ns2:ControlNumber"/>
               </cseiwo:ControlNumber>
               <cseiwo:StateTribeTerritoryCode>
                  <xsl:value-of select="/ns1:EIWORoot/ns1:EIWOBatch/ns1:DocumentBatchHeader/ns2:StateTribeTerritoryCode"/>
               </cseiwo:StateTribeTerritoryCode>
               <cseiwo:EINText>
                  <xsl:value-of select="/ns1:EIWORoot/ns1:EIWOBatch/ns1:DocumentBatchHeader/ns2:EINText"/>
               </cseiwo:EINText>
               <cseiwo:CreationDate>
                  <xsl:value-of select="/ns1:EIWORoot/ns1:EIWOBatch/ns1:DocumentBatchHeader/ns2:CreationDate"/>
               </cseiwo:CreationDate>
               <cseiwo:CreationTime>
                  <xsl:value-of select="/ns1:EIWORoot/ns1:EIWOBatch/ns1:DocumentBatchHeader/ns2:CreationTime"/>
               </cseiwo:CreationTime>
               <xsl:for-each select="/ns1:EIWORoot/ns1:EIWOBatch/ns1:DocumentBatchHeader/ns1:DocumentCode">
                  <eiwo:DocumentCode>
                     <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                  </eiwo:DocumentCode>
               </xsl:for-each>
            </eiwo:DocumentBatchHeader>
            <xsl:for-each select="/ns1:EIWORoot/ns1:EIWOBatch/ns1:EIWO">
               <eiwo:EIWO>
                  <eiwo:IdentifyingInfo>
                     <eiwo:DocumentDate>
                        <xsl:value-of select="./ns1:IdentifyingInfo/ns1:DocumentDate"/>
                     </eiwo:DocumentDate>
                     <eiwo:DocumentActionCode>
                        <xsl:value-of select="./ns1:IdentifyingInfo/ns1:DocumentActionCode"/>
                     </eiwo:DocumentActionCode>
                     <eiwo:CaseIdentifier>
                        <xsl:value-of select="./ns1:IdentifyingInfo/ns1:CaseIdentifier"/>
                     </eiwo:CaseIdentifier>
                     <eiwo:OrderIdentifier>
                        <xsl:value-of select="./ns1:IdentifyingInfo/ns1:OrderIdentifier"/>
                     </eiwo:OrderIdentifier>
                     <eiwo:DocumentTrackingNumber>
                        <xsl:value-of select="./ns1:IdentifyingInfo/ns1:DocumentTrackingNumber"/>
                     </eiwo:DocumentTrackingNumber>
                  </eiwo:IdentifyingInfo>
                  <eiwo:Person>
                     <eiwo:Employee>
                        <eiwo:PersonName>
                           <cseiwo:LastName>
                              <xsl:value-of select="''"/>
                           </cseiwo:LastName>
                           <cseiwo:FirstName>
                              <xsl:value-of select="''"/>
                           </cseiwo:FirstName>
                        </eiwo:PersonName>
                        <eiwo:PersonSSN>
                           <xsl:value-of select="./ns1:Person/ns1:Employee/ns1:PersonSSN"/>
                        </eiwo:PersonSSN>
                     </eiwo:Employee>
                  </eiwo:Person>
               </eiwo:EIWO>
            </xsl:for-each>
            <eiwo:DocumentBatchTrailer>
               <cseiwo:ControlNumber>
                  <xsl:value-of select="''"/>
               </cseiwo:ControlNumber>
               <cseiwo:SentCounts>
                  <xsl:value-of select="''"/>
               </cseiwo:SentCounts>
               <xsl:for-each select=".">
                  <eiwo:DocumentCode>
                     <xsl:value-of select="''"/>
                  </eiwo:DocumentCode>
               </xsl:for-each>
            </eiwo:DocumentBatchTrailer>
         </eiwo:EIWOBatch>
         <eiwo:DocumentFileTrailer>
            <cseiwo:ControlNumber>
               <xsl:value-of select="/ns1:EIWORoot/ns1:DocumentFileTrailer/ns2:ControlNumber"/>
            </cseiwo:ControlNumber>
            <cseiwo:SentCounts>
               <xsl:value-of select="/ns1:EIWORoot/ns1:DocumentFileTrailer/ns2:SentCounts"/>
            </cseiwo:SentCounts>
            <xsl:for-each select="/ns1:EIWORoot/ns1:DocumentFileTrailer/ns1:DocumentCode">
               <eiwo:DocumentCode>
                  <xsl:value-of select="."/>
               </eiwo:DocumentCode>
            </xsl:for-each>
         </eiwo:DocumentFileTrailer>
      </eiwo:EIWORoot>
   </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Expected output:

```xml
<eiwo:EIWORoot xmlns:eiwo="urn:us:gov:hhs:acf:eiwo" xmlns:cseiwo="urn:us:gov:hhs:acf:cseiwo" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="urn:us:gov:hhs:acf:eiwo eIWO.xsd ">
   <eiwo:DocumentFileHeader>
      <cseiwo:ControlNumber></cseiwo:ControlNumber>
      <cseiwo:EINText></cseiwo:EINText>
      <cseiwo:CreationDate></cseiwo:CreationDate>
      <cseiwo:CreationTime></cseiwo:CreationTime>
      <eiwo:DocumentCode></eiwo:DocumentCode>
   </eiwo:DocumentFileHeader>
   <eiwo:EIWOBatch>
      <eiwo:DocumentBatchHeader>
         <cseiwo:ControlNumber></cseiwo:ControlNumber>
         <cseiwo:StateTribeTerritoryCode></cseiwo:StateTribeTerritoryCode>
         <cseiwo:EINText></cseiwo:EINText>
         <cseiwo:CreationDate></cseiwo:CreationDate>
         <cseiwo:CreationTime></cseiwo:CreationTime>
         <eiwo:DocumentCode></eiwo:DocumentCode>
      </eiwo:DocumentBatchHeader>
      <eiwo:EIWO>
         <eiwo:IdentifyingInfo>
            <eiwo:DocumentDate></eiwo:DocumentDate>
            <eiwo:DocumentActionCode></eiwo:DocumentActionCode>
            <eiwo:CaseIdentifier></eiwo:CaseIdentifier>
            <eiwo:OrderIdentifier></eiwo:OrderIdentifier>
            <eiwo:DocumentTrackingNumber></eiwo:DocumentTrackingNumber>
         </eiwo:IdentifyingInfo>
         <eiwo:Person>
            <eiwo:Employee>
               <eiwo:PersonName>
                  <cseiwo:LastName></cseiwo:LastName>
                  <cseiwo:FirstName></cseiwo:FirstName>
               </eiwo:PersonName>
               <eiwo:PersonSSN></eiwo:PersonSSN>
            </eiwo:Employee>
         </eiwo:Person>
      </eiwo:EIWO>
      <eiwo:DocumentBatchTrailer>
         <cseiwo:ControlNumber></cseiwo:ControlNumber>
         <cseiwo:SentCounts></cseiwo:SentCounts>
         <eiwo:DocumentCode></eiwo:DocumentCode>
      </eiwo:DocumentBatchTrailer>
   </eiwo:EIWOBatch>
   <eiwo:DocumentFileTrailer>
      <cseiwo:ControlNumber></cseiwo:ControlNumber>
      <cseiwo:SentCounts></cseiwo:SentCounts>
      <eiwo:DocumentCode></eiwo:DocumentCode>
   </eiwo:DocumentFileTrailer>
</eiwo:EIWORoot>
```

Comment: Oh gosh - ***WHAT A MESS!*** you need to clean up your XML to be properly readable! No one is going to wade through all this mess for you ...

Comment: Please reduce your examples to the minimum required to demonstrate the problem - see: [mcve]. Also make sure your XSLT does not produce an error.

Comment: I've edited your examples to enclose the code in "code blocks" delimited by backticks. Please take the time to edit your question to see how this is done, so you can format your code readably in your next question.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14966266/xslt-move-namespace-declarations-from-child-to-parent-element

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that all you need to do to get the expected output is just:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:eiwo="urn:us:gov:hhs:acf:eiwo" 
xmlns:cseiwo="urn:us:gov:hhs:acf:cseiwo">

<xsl:template match="/eiwo:EIWORoot">
    <eiwo:EIWORoot xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="urn:us:gov:hhs:acf:eiwo eIWO.xsd">
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </eiwo:EIWORoot>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="eiwo:*">
    <xsl:element name="eiwo:{local-name()}">
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="cseiwo:*">
    <xsl:element name="cseiwo:{local-name()}">
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

But I did not check this very thoroughly because your XML is very long.

Please note that the result is semantically identical to the input. With a target application that uses a conforming parser there should be no need to perform this transformation at all.